# How to Get The Excerpt of the page that displays Blog Posts

Tags: archives, blog-page, description

I use a static page (Blog) to display the latest posts. I want to show the excerpt of that page next to the title. However, wen I use `wp_kses_post( get_the_excerpt() )`, I get the excerpt of the latest post from the post archive loop. I also tried with `wp_kses_post( get_the_archive_description() )` but it also does not seem to work.. Any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get_queried_object()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/) to get the static page data, and then do something like so to get the excerpt of the page:

```php
echo get_the_excerpt( get_queried_object() );

// Or to apply filters just as the_excerpt() does:
$excerpt = get_the_excerpt( get_queried_object() );
echo apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', $excerpt );
```

Comment: Awesome, this is working like a charm! Thank you!